# How can I return value after newwork request by Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I want wo get value and return,but always return null,so i print the result

```
func Getex(word :String){
    var temp = WordStruct()
    let url = "http://fanyi.youdao.com/openapi.do?keyfrom=hfutedu&key=842883705&type=data&doctype=json&version=1.1&q="+word
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                temp.word = word
                temp.phonetic = json["basic"]["phonetic"].stringValue
                for (_,val) in json["basic"]["explains"]{
                    temp.explains.append(val.string!)
                }
                //@1print("\(temp)")
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
   //@2 print("\(temp)")
}
```

At @1 I can get the data,but can't get data At @2
how can i return the value temp

```
struct WordStruct {
    var word: String?
    var phonetic:String?
    var explains = [String]()
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at the "Related" section. This has been asked and answered more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire requests are asynchronous by default. So when you call `Alamofire.request` the runtime returns immediately before calling your response block. In order to retrieve the WordStruct you'll need to add a completion block to your `Getex` method.

```
func Getex(word :String, completion: (WordStruct)->())
```

Then in your request completion block where you print @1 instead call

```
//@1print("\(temp)")
completion(temp)
```

Wherever you are calling `Getex`, you'll need to pass a completion block similar to how you do with Alamofire.request. For example:

```
Getex("Test") { word in
     print(word)
}
```

Comment: thanks very much.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390656/how-to-return-value-from-alamofire i read this but not understand
after read your answer,i understand how to use