# Return Value Undefined Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

My current function is as follows:

```
public func getToken() -> String {
    Alamofire.request("url", method: .post, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseData { response in
            if let data = response.data {
                let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data)
                let token  = ((xml["authResponse"] ["authToken"].element?.text))!
            }
        }

    return token // Test is undefined down here
}
```

I am trying to get this function to return the token string but the variable `token` is undefined.

Comment: You should see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390656/how-to-return-value-from-alamofire

Comment: You should also study up on the scope of variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems with this code. The first and most obvious is that `token` is only in scope within the inner closure, so it's not defined where your `return` statement is located. However, the second problem is that your Alamofire request will be made asynchronously, but the signature of your `getToken` method assumes that the resulting value will be provided synchronously.

I'd suggest changing the signature of your method to accept another closure as a parameter as a "callback" method. Something along these lines:

```
public func getToken(callback: ((String?) -> Void)) -> String {
    Alamofire.request("url", method: .post, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseData { response in
            if let data = response.data {
                let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data)
                let token  = ((xml["authResponse"] ["authToken"].element?.text))!
                callback(token)
            } else {
                callback(nil)
            }
        }
}
```

Then, you could call it like this:

```
getToken(callback: { token in
    if let token = token {
        print("Got the token: \(token)")
    } else {
        print("Didn't get the token: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯")
    }
})
```

You'd probably want to add some more robust error handling, and maybe a way to disambiguate between an error and an actual `nil` value being returned (if that's even possible). I'd also suggest getting rid of the forced unwrapping in your `getToken` method. Hopefully this solves your original problem though.