# Unable to change global variable from within function

Tags: swift, alamofire, swxmlhash

I am trying to change a global variable from within an alamofire variable but am having issues doing it. Here is my code:

```
var projects = [[String]]()
var xmlToParse = String()
var postTitle = String()
var postLink = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    httpRequest("https://www.hello.com/feed") { response in
        self.xmlToParse = response as String
        let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(self.xmlToParse)

        for elem in xml["rss"]["channel"]["item"].all {
            self.postTitle = elem["title"].element!.text
            self.postLink = elem["link"].element!.text                
            self.projects.append([self.postTitle, self.postLink])
        }
    }
    print(self.projects)
}
```

When I print self.projects here, i get an empty array, however when I print it inside the httpRequest function I get the proper data. Am I not setting the global variable projects within the for loop? How can I get the value outside of that function? I have tried everything I found on SO with no success. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Just for more info, here is my httpRequest function:

```
func httpRequest(_ section: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(section, method: .get).responseString { response in
        completion(response.result.value!)
    }
}
```

Comment: it is because you are printing self.projects even before httpRequest function calls the completion handler.

Comment: Hmm.. So how can I get it so that projects array can be accessed in ViewDidLoad with the proper data in it, as well as in other functions?

Comment: why not just place your logic within the completion handler?

Comment: I have tried that, but the array is still empty. Do you have an example? I must be doing it wrong somehow

Comment: Learn the difference between async and sync. Search for @escaping functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return value from Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390656/how-to-return-value-from-alamofire)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that xml["rss"]["channel"]["item"] is not nil...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    httpRequest("https://www.hello.com/feed") { response in
        self.xmlToParse = response as String
        let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(self.xmlToParse)

        for elem in xml["rss"]["channel"]["item"].all {
            self.postTitle = elem["title"].element!.text
            self.postLink = elem["link"].element!.text                
            self.projects.append([self.postTitle, self.postLink])
        }

        self.setup()
    }
}

func setup() {
    // Your logic here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am confused what goes in setup though. the original func httpRequest?

Comment: Also, the next thing I'm doing will be error handling for nil :)

Comment: you can put the codes on what you plan to do with self.projects within setup. By doing so, you can ensure that self.projects variable is already assigned with some value.

Comment: the problem is i'm trying to populate a tableview cell with items from the array so i can't call the tableview function in setup

Comment: why not? if you have set your tableview delegate and datasource correctly you can simply do a tableview.reloadData()

Comment: That was it! I completely slipped my mind about reloadData even though I used it elsewhere, thanks so much!!!